# Atomic operations in Riak?

Tags: riak, atomic

I've searched around to figure out whether or not `PUT` operations are atomic in Riak. Are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riak is an eventually consistant system with absolutely no concept of anything atomic.

Probably the best resource for explaining this is our page on the subject: http://wiki.basho.com/Eventual-Consistency.html